# Automatically download image from server

Tags: android, image, download

**How to download images from server without pressing the button in Android Studio. The code runs ok but only if I press the button to download. How to make automatically download the image**

@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.bDownloadImage:
                new DonwloadImage(downloadImageName.getText().toString()).execute();
                break;
        }
    }

```
private class DonwloadImage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {
    String name;
    ProgressDialog loading;
    public DonwloadImage (String name){//constractor
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Receiver.this);
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Downloading Image");   // title of progress dialog
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");    // message displaying
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();    // show method
    }


    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        // loading.dismiss();
        String url = SERVER_ADDRESS + "pictures/" + name + ".JPG";
        try
        {
            URLConnection connection = new URL(url).openConnection();
            connection.setConnectTimeout(1000 * 30);
            connection.setReadTimeout(1000 * 30);

            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) connection.getContent(), null, null);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
        if(bitmap != null)
        {
            downloadImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Step #1: Choose your trigger event that will require the download. Step #2: Execute your `AsyncTask` when that event occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should add

```
DonwloadImage(downloadImageName.getText().toString()).execute();
```

in onCreate of Activity, for autoDownload property.

Comment: Yeah true but had also to add. new DonwloadImage(downloadImageName.getText().toString()).execute(); . Thank you bthw.